# flyway database script logging

Tags: sql, database, logging, flyway

I am currently evaluating Flyway software as a deployment option for our
company.  We run our database deployments on an ORACLE database and
currently spool the output from a sqlplus session for logging purposes.  We
use this to verify feedback information such as were objects created
successfully, were packages and  functions, etc. compiled without errors,
verify amount of records entered and so forth.

Is there similar  logging functionality in Flyway?   Currently the only
logging we have found is in the server logs.  We can tell from these logs
that a script has completed successfully or has triggered an ORA error but
we are curious as to whether this is the extent of the database logging
options or not.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

We used the command line method for running flyway and turned on debug output (`-X`). Along with a lot of other output it also logs more information about the SQL migrations run (eg content of repeatable migrations) and the number of records affected. This is not perfect however it helped us a lot in capturing more information about what was applied.

See https://flywaydb.org/documentation/commandline/ as it is not documented for each individual command as it applies to flyway itself.